# content jumps when sticky navbar get fixed position

Tags: jquery

In first scroll navigation jumps to fix at once and content goes under navigation at once overall this is an awkward phenomenon wants to get rid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add margin to the content div when u change navbar to fixed position.

space of the element will be take off when with position: fixed; setting

Answer (score 1):

When you take the navbar out of the page flow (to fixed), the elements that were below jump upward to fill the newly empty space.

Wrap the navbar in a new element that will occupy the space when the navbar goes to fixed. The element will need its width and height to be set, since it too will be empty once the navbar is fixed position.